# When groovy calls bash, debug mode "-x" is not visible in the standard output

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, stdout, stderr

We're using groovy to execute a bash script that has debug mode `set -x` in it. We're running it like so:

```
    def proc = "bash hello.sh".execute()  
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitForOrKill(100*1000)
```

When we run it directly from command prompt with `bash hello.sh`, we see echo lines and + lines:

```
Tue Jun 11 10:52:42 IDT 2013:: Running 
+ mkdir -p folder
+ tar -xzf file
...
```

But when we run it from groovy, only the echo lines are visible!

```
Tue Jun 11 10:52:42 IDT 2013:: Running
```

What's the deal? Is this a groovy/Java bug?

Comment: Debug messages go to standard error, not standard output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
proc.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

Before you wait for it to finish (in place of your `proc.in.eachLine` line)

Comment: Thanks, will try it! will it allow for real time printing of stdout and stderr while we wait for it to finish? Or will I have to dump everything after the process ends?

Comment: It will spawn a thread for each stream, and will print while waiting for the process to end